# Closed subgroups of $Z_{p}^{\times}$

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, topological-groups, p-adic-number-theory

I was able to prove that any closed subgroup of additive group of $Z_{p}$ is of the form $p^{n}Z_{p}$ for some $n$. I asked the same question for the multiplicative group of units in $Z_{p}$, that is $Z_{p}^{\times}$. Since it has the direct product decomposition ${\mu}_{p-1}{\times}(1+pZ_{p})$ I ran into trouble. I thought of finding closed subgroups of $(1+pZ_{p})$ but I fear that may not help since subgroups of $A{\times}B$ are not always of the form (*subgroup of* $A$ ${\times}$ *subgroup of* $B$). I don't know how to proceed. Any hints, suggestions are welcome. Thanks!!

Comment: In this case, since you can write $\Bbb Z_p^\times\cong\Bbb F_p^\times\times(1+p\Bbb Z_p)$, and the first factor is of order prime to $p$ while the second is, in essence, a $p$-group, subgroups of the product really are of the form that you were fearful wouldn’t suffice.